# DateTime::createFromFormat is returning false even though it shouldn't

Tags: php

I am trying to make sure a date is a valid date, it is like so 07/24/2015 - 07/24/2015

This is my code to make sure it's value

```
//split the start and end date in to 2 and compare both to a real date to make sure they're valid
        $newdate = explode("-", $start);

        //echo 1;
        //make sure date 2 is set
        if(!isset($newdate[1])): Session::set('error', 13); return false; endif;

        //check if newdate 0 and 1 are real dates
        $date1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y', str_replace("/","-",$newdate[0]));
        $date2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y', str_replace("/","-",$newdate[1]));

        echo date("m-d-Y").'<br/>';
        echo str_replace("/","-",$newdate[0]);

        var_dump($date1);
        var_dump($date2);
        //not valid dates
        if($date1 == false || $date2 == false): Session::set('error',13); return false; endif;
```

I have tried it with, and without str_replace, I have compared the date("m-d-Y"); to my $newdate with str_replace and they match perfect, but I am still getting a (bool)false with my dates even though they're valid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start by fixing the explode to be on `' - '`, since `'-'` is leaving extra spaces at the beginning and end of your date strings. That will fix it. Shown here: https://eval.in/404554

Next, you don't need to bother with str_replace on them.

```
$dates = '07/24/2015 - 07/24/2015';
$newdate = explode(" - ", $dates);

$date1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $newdate[0]);
$date2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $newdate[1]);
```

Valid dates: https://eval.in/404555

Comment: LOL. Damn. I feel like an idiot. I've been going over my code for the past hour. This has fixed it. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome :) Don't feel too bad, we all get stuck on stuff :) Please accept as answer when you can :)